# GWT 2.4.0 Touch Screen

Tags: java, gwt, touchscreen

I am doing some research behind GWT 2.4.0 to find out whether it supports touch screen for a PC monitor, preferably 24" widescreen.

I've been trawling their website in hopes of finding this information, but to no avail, and a Google search doesn't seem to be bringing up any concrete evidence.

I've seen that you can create mobile UI using GWT but I'm not certain whether that is included in the 2.4.0 version, or if it was added in a later version, 2.5.0 +.

If anyone has any expertise with GWT and can help me out with this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need touch support you could use MGWT: https://github.com/mgwt/mgwt